# JQuery - Change element's position on blur

Tags: jquery, css, position, css-position, blur

I am trying to allow the user to type in a number in an input box and once they unfocus that textbox, update an element's position to whatever number was entered in the textbox.

CSS:

```
<style>
#area
{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#item
{
    position:absolute;
    left:20px;
    top:40px;
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    background-color:red;
}
</style>
```

jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#textbox").blur(function() {
        var x = document.getElementById('textbox').value;
        $("#item").css("left") = x;    
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="area"> 
    <div id="item"></div>
</div><br />
<input type="text" id="textbox"></input>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vuLPq/14/

This line `$("#item").css("left") = x;` does not seem to work. The div's position does not update. Can anyone see the issue?

Comment: try this $("#item").css("left",x+"px"); instead of $("#item").css("left") = x;

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You can't assign to the `css()` function
2. The value you're passing should contain units (probably pixels, in this case)

```js
 $("#textbox").blur(function() {
     var x = $(this).val() + "px";
     $("#item").css("left", x);    
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
$("#item").css("left") = x;
```

To:

```
$("#item").css("left", x + "px");
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vuLPq/20/)**

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things you might find useful. First, inside the blur event you have access to the object already, so you do not need to do `document.getElementByID` you can simply do `this.value`.

Second, to change a css property, you don't set it equal so you must change

```
$("#item").css("left") = x;
```

To

```
$("#item").css("left", x + "px");
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vuLPq/17/

Answer (score 1):

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3sym/1/)**

Provide the value in 'px' or 'em'. Use `this.value`.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#textbox").blur(function() {
        $("#item").css("left",this.value+'em');   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this:

    http://jsfiddle.net/appleBud/vuLPq/25/

You are just missing px with your value.
Hope it helps.
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
$("#textbox").keypress(function() {
    var x = $(this).val();       
    $("#item").animate({left:x}) 

    });
 });
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/vuLPq/29/

you can use it with blur aswel. keypress will update the position as you enter the value